# How can I post an article on Stack Overflow with a 'dofollow' link?

Tags: discussion, collectives, articles, seo

I am new here and I work for a [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) blog website. I want to submit an article here with a *dofollow* link and in the future, I will submit a more unique article according to my niche.

I have got [these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/propose-article), but this is unclear: "Make sure you are on the landing page for a collective and click the "Propose article" button on the right", but I couldn't find any button to post the article.

Comment: As I posted on the question before it was migrated: I think articles are supposed to be self-contained on stackoverflow and not just an excuse to link to your website. So I doubt that your article would be welcome.

Comment: Articles are unique to Collectives, and there is no Wordpress Collective.

Comment: It's nice that you checked how to post an article, but did you actually check [what Stack Overflow exists for](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in the first place?

Comment: @Larnu Even then, they work at "a WP blog", not for (or on or with)  WP itself. The article could be about anything, but it probably isn't about WordPress, so it would be off-topic even if a WP collective existed.

Comment: I didn't click the (now removed) link, but I *assumed* good faith and that they (or the company they work for) were, in some way, affiliated with Wordpress, @ZoestandswithUkraine .

Answer (score 22):

You don't.

Stack Overflow isn't here to help you with your SEO. Advertising your own content here is a good way to get banned fast. Questions and answers are expected to be self-contained, and linking to non-official resources is not appreciated.